# Why do I get this unexpected output of printf?

Tags: c

I tried to understand how `printf` works in these cases: (it's a bonus question from a test)

Case 1:

```
int d=1;
printf("%d",(int)"printf("%d);
```

The output: `0`

Case 2: (with out the `%d` at the end)

```
int d=1;
printf("%d",(int)"printf(");
```

The output: `15554368`

How does this work? And why does `%d` make it different?

Comment: What is this nonsense?? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: Uhh...... what?

Comment: First is printing remainder of pointer divided by `d`. Second is printing the pointer value. Nonsense as stated.

Comment: `printf("%d",(int)printf("%d")); ///// printf("%d",(int)printf(""));` --- OP did you mean this??

Comment: 'i try unsderstand how printf works in this cases' - a waste of your time.  Wherever this code came from, try to forget it and move on with your life.

Comment: @Coldspeed It seems to be pretty consistent.

Comment: @Coldspeed you really think? Then how do you explain the existence of the second example?

Comment: its a bonus question from test...

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Looks like some excerpt from Obfuscated C Code Contest... That could be a funny game, so why not?

Comment: @KenWhite bogus dupe

Comment: When you are saying "unexpected" it is usually implying that you have some expectations? What are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bonus question is a trick question:

`printf("%d",(int)"printf("%d);` is parsed as

```
printf(
       "%d",
       ((int)"printf(") % d
      );
```

The address of the string `"printf("` is converted to `int` and the modulus operation is computed.  Since `d = 1`, the modulus is always `0`.  Hence `printf` outputs `0`.

The second call just prints the address of the string converted to `int`, something that will vary from one environment to another, it may even vary from one run to another (it does on my Mac)...

As a matter of fact, the conversion may even fail and trigger implementation specific behavior. So the answer really should be *implementation defined behavior in both cases.*

Another question should have been:

```
int d=1;
printf("%d",(int)printf("%d", d));
```

Which produces `11`. Can you explain why?

Note that even this last question is tricky: calling `printf` without a proper prototype, for example if `<stdio.h>` is not included, has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with the second example:

```
int d=1;
printf("%d",(int)"printf(");
```

`"printf("` here is a string constant, only containing the name of a C function in an attempt to confuse you. A string constant has the type `char *`, it's a pointer to the first character. The `(int)` converts the pointer to an integer. While this is *implementation defined*, you will get *some* value that is related to the address at which the string `"printf("` is actually stored.

So you print a number here that happens to be the result of a pointer converted to `int`.

Moving on:

```
int d=1;
printf("%d",(int)"printf(" % d);
```

There's only one change, and I added spaces to make it obvious: The `int` you get from your pointer conversion is taken *modulo `d`*, so the result is the remainder of the integer division by `d`. As `d` is one, there will be never any remainder, any number is divisable by 1 without a remainder. Therefore the result is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The second `%d` is not a `printf()` specifier, it's the `%` modulo division operator and the `int` variable `d` which has a value of `1`, what is the difference? they are not alike at all.

The second problem, is that you are casting a pointer to `int`, which is not well defined.